# How to embed content script into web views?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I want to work with the content in the webview (eg. submit a form) - for this, I thought I could do this by embedding some scripts into it. But when I use content_scripts, I get a warning saying 'Content Scripts are allowed only in legacy packaged apps"

I searched about 'Legacy packaged apps'  but couldn't find any information about that via google.

Is is possible to insert content scripts into webviews in Chrome apps? or is there any other good alternative solution to get this.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ExecuteScript](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/P-jaZOCD54s) rather than content scripts in webviews. It's almost the same as the [programmatic-injection kind of content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) that you're probably already familiar with.

Comment: Hi @sowbug thank you for the reply

for ExecuteScript, I get 'ExecuteScript' does not exist for webview object. I tried the adding 'tabs' permission for which again I get the legacy packaged app warning message. Am I missing something in the configuration.

Comment: It looks like you're spelling it wrong (note capitalization). Also be sure you're running a new enough version of Chrome. Dev channel is probably new enough.